# Array and reversed giving same result but not equal

Tags: arrays, swift, reverse

Im came across a situation which is difficult to understand. I have array of strings and then reversed but it prints the same array instead of reversing...

When compared, compiler says they are not equal

Below is the code...

Please help me understanding this phenomenon

```
let names = ["Andy", "Joy", "Paul"]
print(names) // Prints  ["Andy", "Joy", "Paul"]
print(names.reversed()) 
//Prints ReversedCollection<Array<String>>(_base: ["Andy", "Joy", "Paul"])`

//Prints Not equal
if names == names.reversed() {
    print("Equal")
} else {
    print("Not Equal")
}
```

I was expecting output to be 
["Paul", "Joy", "Andy"] after

```
 names.reversed()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `reversed()` doesn't modify the array. It returns a view to the original array.

When you call `print(names.reversed())`, it prints that reversed list but `names` itself is left unchanged.

The only time `names == names.reversed()` would be true is if the array was empty or it was a "palindrome" array.

Also keep in mind that you declared `names` as a constant (using `let`) so that should be a good hint that `names` hasn't been modified.

You could create a new array:

```
let reversedNames = names.reversed()
```

That new array will have the value in reversed order.

Comment: Don't forget to mention `Reverse()`  as that do what he wishes for

Comment: @Vollan You mean `reverse()`, not `Reverse()`. That only works on variables, not constants.

Comment: @maddy Yes, thank you.  I missed that it was a constant. But get a feeling that iti s what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The result has not been processed yet (the ReversedCollection is `lazy`).

Please try mapping the results:

[ReversedCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/reversedcollection)

Answer (score 0):

As the Apple Document states

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed

> You can reverse a collection **without allocating new space** for its elements by calling this reversed() method. A ReversedCollection instance wraps an underlying collection and provides access to its elements in reverse order. This example prints the characters of a string in reverse order:
>
> ```
> let word = "Backwards"
> for char in word.reversed() {
>     print(char, terminator: "")
> }
> // Prints "sdrawkcaB"
> ```
>
> If you need a reversed collection of the same type, you may be able to use the collection’s sequence-based or **collection-based initializer**. For example, to get the reversed version of a string, reverse its characters and **initialize a new String instance** from the result.
>
> ```
> let reversedWord = String(word.reversed())
> print(reversedWord)
> // Prints "sdrawkcaB"
> ```

In your case you need to create a new instance like below

```
let reversedArray = names.reversed()
print(reversedArray) 
// Prints ["Paul", "Joy", "Andy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

after writing

```
print(names.reversed())
```

//Prints ReversedCollection>(_base: ["Andy", "Joy", "Paul"])`

1). your array is reversed but that is not store in names so name is as it is at now.

2). when you reversed array at print time then that display ReversedCollection so that collection is reversed but not stored at now so that just manage internal for reverse array.

if you store in some object then that object print then that display reversed.

like:

```
let reversedName = names.reversed()
print(reversedName)
```

so it's print reversed array.